# Can a Laplace transform kernel be viewed as a test function?

Tags: laplace-transform, distribution-theory

Was trying to grasp the concept of distributions recently, and i was asking myself if the kernel of Laplace transform can be viewed as a "test function" that maps the the function of interest in an eigenbasis.

By that i mostly mean that as a test function is measuring another function point as a weighted average of its neiborhood, is the exponential from the Laplace transform doing the same thing ?

Comment: you should insert your qualifying comment into the question, I think.

Comment: Replacing $C^\infty_c$ by things like $\{ e^{-st},\Re(s) > c\}$ is the idea of analytic functionals. For example $\delta(y-i)$ is such an analytic functional, well defined for $F$ the Fourier transform of $f(t)=O(e^{-2|t|})$. it is the Fourier transform of $f(t)\to e^t f(t)$.